# Rails alternative for only_provides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I'd like to limit response formats available for a single action inside a controller. What I have so far (and works):

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  ...

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

This is not as DRY as I'd like. In Merb you could do `only_provides :html` inside a method to get about the same effect. Is there something like that in Rails 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :except => :show
  respond_to :html

  def show

  end
end
```